# Could x264 do the audio recording job on Android

Tags: android, audio, x264

I am trying to use [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) on Android to build a video system, which could do the encoding and decoding work. I've finished the video data capturing and encoding work. But I am not sure about how to deal with the audio stuff. Does x264 support audio recording? Or should I use some other api provided by Android? If I do the video capturing and audio capturing job seperately, how could I make sure they are time synchronization?

Answer (score 0):

The x264 is only a video codec. For audio you need to use some audio codec (for example aac could be used here). Having these you can merge them into output file (.mkv or whatever you have).

https://sites.google.com/site/linuxencoding/x264-encoding-guide

Comment: Thanks! Is there API I can use?